# SwiftUI - How to make navigation bar title editable (without changing any other behavior)?

Tags: swiftui, textfield, navigationbar

I really like the look of the navigation bar title in SwiftUI, and I like that it appears just below the safe area, but appears in the principal part of the toolbar when you scroll down. I'm wondering how to completely replicate this look and behavior but make it editable by the user (most likely through a textfield?)

I've tried

```
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
    TextField("Navigation Title", text: $mainTitle)
  }
}
```

But this simply places the title in the toolbar at all times, rather than only when you scroll slightly.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want the large nav title AND the small one in the navbar? Or only the small in navbar?

Comment: Both, but at different times. The large nav title when scrolled to the top of the screen (without the small one), then the small one when you scroll slightly down. Also worth noting that the large title animates into the small one for a standard nav bar title

Comment: I thought so :) There is no real way to do this in SwitUI, because you can't access the behavior of the title. Of course you could "custom rebuild" it in some way.

Answer (score 1):

First I explain why your code does not work:
Only the size of the navigationTitle changes when you start to scroll, not the size of the whole toolbar or its items.

But I think I have a solution:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var title: String = "Title"
    @State private var titleSmall: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        .onChange(of: geo.frame(in: .global).minY) { val in
                            if val <= 53.5 {
                                titleSmall = true
                            } else {
                                titleSmall = false
                            }
                        }
                }
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    TextField("Title", text: $title)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(titleSmall ? .headline : .largeTitle.bold())
                        .accessibilityAddTraits(.isHeader)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What the code does is: It gets the top Y position from the first (in this example) list item.
Then it checks if the first list item is under the title bar and changes the font size of the title if necessary.
The only Problem I see is that there is a pretty rough transition between small and big title but I think you can figure out how to fix this.

If you have more questions how the code works just ask

I hope that solves your question.

And I would recommend to have a look at Paul Hudson’s video about the Geometry Reader (he’s a great YouTuber): https://youtu.be/kh9lnIYgW1E

I just realized that it says „OLD“ in the video title, so it may be outdated.
But he has some other videos about the Geometry Reader.
just search for „Paul Hudson Geometry Reader“